# Want to keep button besides the text area

Tags: html, textarea, overlap, right-align

In HTML, I want to align a button besides a text-area like in a messenger:

[image: Like this]

Both are in the footer, but when I change the screen size, this happens:

[image: This happens]

```
<input type="button" value="➢" onclick="CheckAndSubmit ()" style=" position:fixed; bottom:4px;right:100px; padding:15px;">
<textarea name="message" id="message" cols="40" rows="1" style="position:fixed; padding:15px; bottom:4px;"></textarea>
```

Comment: You should provide code with your questions othervise no one will guess here

Comment: @Beloo okay ,thanks i will keep that in mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is to use Bootstrap, you can read more about it here; http://getbootstrap.com/.

To use bootstrap, put this in your html -tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

In your HTML code, you can then simply write:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        // Input field goes here
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2>
        // Button goes here
    </div>
</div>
```